# Register views with regions depending on the user rights in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, prism

We have a module class which implements the IModule interface and it has only one method Initialize() in which we register our views.
Is it possible to register these views after successful login?

I want to prohibit the registration of several views depending on the current user. But the user logs on after the module initialization.

Is there a way to provide a callback where Prism can evaluate if the registration is active? Or do I have the chance to disable registrations of the Region Manager? Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to communicate among multiple modules (or even within) in Prism is using the EventAggregator. Here is what I would do:

1. Create a CompositePresentationEvent for UserLoginEvent that takes relevant parameter regarding the user
2. Publish the event using IEventAggregator when the user successfully logs in
3. On your module initialize, subscribe to the UserLoginEvent, in the handler register the appropriate views
4. Repeat the above, but opposite, for UserLogout if desired.

In your infrastructure lib:

```
public class UserLoginEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<User> { }
```

Then in your module:

```
public class YourModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;
    private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;
    private readonly IEventAggregator events;

    public YourModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager manager, IEventAggregator events)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.regionManager = manager;
        this.events = events;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        ....
        events.GetEvent<UserLoginEvent>().Subscribe(RegisterUserViews);
    }

    private void RegisterUserViews(User u)
    {
            // check user permissions
            // register and create views using container, regionManager
    }
}
```

In whatever module / code your user logs in... I assume you can get the IEventAggregator (similar to above) and then do something like:

```
OnUserLogin(User u)
{
    eventAggregator.GetEvent<UserLoginEvent>().Publish(u);
}
```

Hope this helps! if a user logs out, then you may want to store references to your views in your module and remove them on a UserLogoutEvent which would work like the above code but just doing the opposite.

Comment: it doesn't call the event subscribed in Module. I have another solution to set InitializationMode to OnDemand.

Comment: @HEMANTPATNECHA are you publishing the event?